# I want to send my response to an API using TOTP?

Tags: python, json, api, automation, command-line-interface

I want to sent my assignment gist in the JSON Response :
{
gist :"",
email :""
}
to an API using TOTP(Time-based one-time password) method . Is there any solution available for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have to do it by yourself but still if you invested lot's of time and didn't find solution then you can use my solution for that:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import sys
import struct
import json

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

root = "YOUR API RESIDES HERE"
content_type = "application/json"
userid = "YOUR USERID"
secret_suffix = "YOUR SECRET SUFFIX OR KEY"
shared_secret = userid+secret_suffix

timestep = 30
T0 = 0

def HOTP(K, C, digits=10):
    """HTOP:
    K is the shared key
    C is the counter value
    digits control the response length
    """
    K_bytes = str.encode(K)
    C_bytes = struct.pack(">Q", C)
    hmac_sha512 = hmac.new(key = K_bytes, msg=C_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    return Truncate(hmac_sha512)[-digits:]

def Truncate(hmac_sha512):
    """truncate sha512 value"""
    offset = int(hmac_sha512[-1], 16)
    binary = int(hmac_sha512[(offset *2):((offset*2)+8)], 16) & 0x7FFFFFFF
    return str(binary)

def TOTP(K, digits=10, timeref = 0, timestep = 30):
    """TOTP, time-based variant of HOTP
    digits control the response length
    the C in HOTP is replaced by ( (currentTime - timeref) / timestep )
    """
    C = int ( time.time() - timeref ) // timestep
    return HOTP(K, C, digits = digits)

data = {
  "github_url": "YOUR GITHUB URL",
  "contact_email": "YOUR EMAIL",
  "solution_language": "IT IS OPTIONAL"
}
passwd = TOTP(shared_secret, 10, T0, timestep).zfill(10) 
resp = requests.post(root, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userid, passwd), data=json.dumps(data))
print(resp.json())
```